# Difference between similar FFT code on complete signal or averaged on chunks

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have 2 snippets of code that should produce the same result. In the first one, I consider a 2500 sample signal on 64 channels sampled at 500 Hz; and in the second one, I cut down this signal into 5 chunks of 500 samples each.

```
# Snippet 1: 
data = get_data() # data shape is 64x2500

# Snippet 2:
data = get_data().reshape(64, 5, 500) # data shape is 64x5x500
```

Where `get_data()` is just a placeholder for this example, feel free to generate a random sample array to use with both pieces of code. In practice, to test my code I duplicated a sample signal with `copy.deepcopy()`.

My goal is to extract the frequency power on 2 bands by averaging on the band and across all 64 channels.

- alpha: (8, 13) Hz
- delta: (1, 4) Hz

To do so, I apply a fast Fourier transform through `numpy`: (The code below should work on both snippets with both array dimensions.)

```
import numpy as np

alpha = (8, 13)
delta = (1, 4)
fs = 500. # sampling frequency

frequencies = np.fft.rfftfreq(data.shape[-1], 1.0/fs)
alpha_band = np.where(np.logical_and(frequencies>=alpha[0], 
                                     frequencies<=alpha[1]))[0]
delta_band = np.where(np.logical_and(frequencies>=delta[0], 
                                     frequencies<=delta[1]))[0]

fftval = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(data, axis=-1) / fs)
```

The absolute values are then squared. Moreover, each of the 64 channels also has a weight applied to it via multiplication. To test the code, I set all weights to 1.

```
weights = np.ones(shape=(64,))
alpha = np.average(np.multiply(np.square(fftval[..., alpha_band]).T, weights))
delta = np.average(np.multiply(np.square(fftval[..., delta_band]).T, weights))
```

My understanding was that averaging across chunks should not change the result. Yet, here are the 2 outputs I got on the same data:

```
# Snippet 1, 64x2500
alpha
Out: 5.294149596657551e-13

delta
Out: 9.372696436349552e-13

alpha/delta
Out: 0.564848081084284

# Snippet 2: 64x5x500
alpha
Out: 6.326672955916193e-12

delta
Out: 7.584706602278469e-13

alpha/delta
Out: 8.34135489699185
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here and why both results are completely different? What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only with a "perfect" signal for you sampling freq and chunking the average of chunk's spectra and full signal spectra will be the same.

You should apply windowing (e.g. np.hamming) to the signal, especially if you are looking for soo low-freq components as you are.

The fft (dft) is cyclic and start and end meet and if there are low freq components which does not repeat itself many times (or even once) the start and end will be discontinous when connected. The effects of this is called spectral leak. It "creates" false high freq components which disturbs the overall result. The choice of window function is dependant of your needs.. So not totally straight-forward but test some and see if it improves!

Here is a good resource on windowing https://download.ni.com/evaluation/pxi/Understanding%20FFTs%20and%20Windowing.pdf

Repeat the test but in snippet 1 do windowing on whole signal. In snippet 2 do windowing on each chunk. Problably the results wont be exactly the same even now but hopefully closer!

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. It does make more sense to me now. The results still differ and I still have a hard time figuring out which window and which result is best, but your answer and link already helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is here:

```
fftval[..., alpha_band]
```

For snippet 2 it`s ok, fft values respets to frequencies [8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13.]
But for snippet 1 frequencies for your alpha band are [1.6, 1.8, 2. , 2.2, 2.4, 2.6] Hz
Also

```
fftval = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(data, axis=-1) / data.shape[-1])
```

Comment: I don't think so. 'frequencies = np.fft.rfftfreq(data.shape[-1], 1.0/fs)': in snippet 1 'data.shape[-1]' is 2500 and in snippet 2 it is 500. Thus the frequencies are correctly defined. However, you are correct the normalization is wrong.

Comment: Yep, you are right. But for snippet 1 fftval averaging through 25 values, most of it close to zero. For snippet 2 averaging 5 values, that`s why it much larger.